# Can i take sand from a Japanese beach for educational purposes?

Tags: japan, beaches, souvenirs

I'm going for a trip to Japan and I planned getting a jar of sand from a local beach. It's for my geography teacher, she collects sands from across the world in the classroom, she has already over 40 different varieties, and I thought that it would complete her collection.
I just wanted to make sure it's legal, because I didn't find any information about it online.
If you know something or did that before, please share your experience, I would really appreciate that:))

Comment: The answer to this question depends on at least two things, neither of which you specify, the actual beach in Japan and the country (or even state/province) you return to. If in doubt, do not take it.

Comment: Even if it’s legal, why would anyone still do this in an age of environmental awareness? https://www.rd.com/article/why-you-should-think-twice-before-taking-sand-home-as-a-souvenir/

Comment: I don't know how to reply to the comments, but thank you for the article and advice! I think I'll pass on that kind of souvenir, maybe if some souvenir shop will offer, but definitely not by myself.  Thank you guys!^^